# ColdFusion CFScript Dynamic Name of Function Sets

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

1. How can I make a list of form fields test1 = "firstname,lastname,mode, etc"
   My goal is to move the code to a object so I can just pass it in.

   ```
   <cfinvoke component="#request.componentdir#.tars.tars" method="init" returnvariable="oTars">

   <cfscript>
       test1 = 'mode';
       if(isDefined("session.formFields.#test1#") and session.formFields.#test1# neq ''){
           oTars.set#test1#(session.formFields.#test1#);
       }

       test2 = 'mode';

       if(isDefined("session.formFields.#test2#") and evaluate("session.formFields.#test2#") neq ''){
           evaluate(oTars.set#test1#(session.formFields.#test2#));
       }
   </cfscript>
   <cfdump var="#oTars#">
   ```

Comment: The question is not entirely clear, but if you are using cfinvoke to run the init method of a cfc, you might be on the wrong path altogether.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion gives you a list of all the field names, that are a part of the post request, within the `form` scope. The key name is 
"FieldNames".

So

```
<cfset test1 = Form.FieldNames>
```